# Android permissions "com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.*"

Tags: android-permissions

I have observed a set of Android applications requesting permissions starting with the prefix "com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.*", such as:

```
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.youtube
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.wise
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.fusiontables
com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp
```

etc.

Does anyone know if these permissions are internal permissions of Google apps? or are they deprecated permissions? are intended for use by third-party apps?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a "live permission", according to [AndroidPermissions.COM](http://androidpermissions.com/permission/com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH). That site claims to list [All permissions which are found on a clean Android 4.4 emulator](http://www.androidpermissions.com/).

> **com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH:**
>    View configured accounts
>    Allows apps to see the usernames (email addresses) of the Google account(s) you have configured.

Find the full list of the "sub-permissions" (and their explanations) behind the second link.

**Are intended for use by third-party apps?**

I gather, some yes, some not. I deduce this from code snippets I just [found on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1580827&page=11). Exemple snippet:

```
 <permission android:label="@string/permlab_googleAuth" android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" android:protectionLevel="normal" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.ACCOUNTS" android:description="@string/permdesc_googleAuth" />
 <permission android:label="@string/permlab_googleAuth_ALL" android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES" android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.ACCOUNTS" android:description="@string/permdesc_googleAuth_ALL" />
 <permission android:label="@string/permlab_googleAuth_OTHER" android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.OTHER_SERVICES" android:protectionLevel="dangerous" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.ACCOUNTS" android:description="@string/permdesc_googleAuth_OTHER" />
 <permission android:label="@string/permlab_googleAuth_mail" android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail" android:protectionLevel="dangerous" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.ACCOUNTS" android:description="@string/permdesc_googleAuth_mail" />
 <permission android:label="@string/permlab_googleAuth_cl" android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cl" android:protectionLevel="dangerous" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.ACCOUNTS" android:description="@string/permdesc_googleAuth_cl" />
```

As you can see, the basic `GOOGLE_AUTH` described above has `android:protectionLevel="normal"`, which is accessible to all apps (and not even shown to the user as permission on app install) – while `GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES` is assigned `android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"` (reserved to system apps). So we have the full spectrum here.